# python xlrd: convert xls to csv using tempfiles. Tempfile is empty

Tags: parsing, csv, xlrd

I am downloading an xls file from the internet. It is in .xls format but I need 'Sheet1' to be in csv format. I use xlrd to make the conversion but seem to have run into an issue where the file I write to is empty?

```
import urllib2
import tempfile
import csv
import xlrd

url_2_fetch = ____
u = urllib2.urlopen(url_2_fetch)
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=u.read())
sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
csv_temp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
with open('csv_temp_file', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        writer.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
```

That seemed to have worked. But now I want to inspect the values by doing the following:

```
with open('csv_temp_file', 'rb') as z:
    reader = csv.reader(z)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

But I get nothing:

```
>>> with open('csv_temp_file', 'rb') as z:
...     reader = csv.reader(z)
...     for row in reader:
...             print row
...
>>>
```

I am using a tempfile because I want to do more parsing of the content and then use SQLAlchemy to store the contents of the csv post more parsing to a mySQL database.

I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely wrong:

```
csv_temp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
with open('csv_temp_file', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
```

The `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` call returns "*a file-like object that can be used as a temporary storage area. The file will be destroyed as soon as it is closed (including an implicit close when the object is garbage collected).*"

So your variable `csv_temp_file` contains a file object, already open, that you can read and write to, and will be deleted as soon as you call `.close()` on it, overwrite the variable, or cleanly exit the program.

So far so good. But then you proceed to open another file `with open('csv_temp_file', 'wb')` that is not a temporary file, is created in the script's current directory with the fixed name `'csv_temp_file'`, is overwritten every time this script is run, can cause security holes, strange bugs and race conditions, and is not related to the variable `csv_temp_file` in any way.

You should trash the `with open` statement and use the `csv_temp_file` variable you already have. You can try to `.seek(0)` on it before using it again with the csv reader, it should work. Call `.close()` on it when you are done with it and the temporary file will be deleted.

Comment: question for you: If I perform the xls_2_csv conversion in a function away from the main() body should I create the tempfile in the function or in the main() body and pass it to the xls_2_csv function for manipulation, after which I can return it and assign to another variable? Will that work? I appreciate your *best* coding practice advice. :)

Comment: If you're asking about best practices, I wouldn't use a temporary file at all. I would just read the file into an array `data = [sh.row_values(r) for r in range(sh.nrows)]` and return the array. Then some other code can do the processing and the inserts.